# Ember Data (RESTAdapter) & JSON

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a setup an Ember App and I am having trouble displaying the data from the JSON file. I keep on getting the following error:

```
    Error while processing route: campaigns.index
["No model was found for 'campaign'"]
```

My JSON is setup as

```
{ "campaigns":
   [
       {"id":"1","campaign_name":"Necessitatibus et.","campaign_code":"YQADM","description":"1","effective_from":"2014-11-24 14:33:07","products":"Loans","type":"Gold"},
       {"id":"2","campaign_name":"Voluptatem sequi adipisci necessitatibus.","campaign_code":"VFYGTO","description":"1","effective_from":"2014-11-24 14:33:07","products":"Loans","type":"Gold"}
   ]
}
```

My route is

```
TM.CampaignsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){      
        return this.store.find("campaigns")
    } 
});
```

I have defined the attributes as

```
TM.Campaigns = DS.Model.extend({
    campaign_name: DS.attr()
    campaign_code: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr(),
    effective_from: DS.attr(),
    products: DS.attr(),
    type: DS.attr()
});
```

This seems to be what is required according to the RESTAdapter documentation on the Ember site but I still cannot avoid this error.

I have control over what is outputted from the JSON which is useful. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ember data expects model names to be singular, and not pluralized. So just take the `s` off your model name and you should be good to go.

```
TM.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
  campaign_name: DS.attr()
  campaign_code: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
  effective_from: DS.attr(),
  products: DS.attr(),
  type: DS.attr()
});
```

You'll notice the error message points this out when it says it can't find the `campaign` model.

Comment: I've changed the model and now it's saying - No model was found for 'campaigns'.

Answer (score 0):

So I carried changing the plural to singular wherever the word 'campaigns' was being used and found out that I also had to change my route to

```
TM.CampaignsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){      
        return this.store.find("campaign")
    } 
});
```

as well as the model

```
TM.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
  campaign_name: DS.attr()
  campaign_code: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
  effective_from: DS.attr(),
  products: DS.attr(),
  type: DS.attr()
});
```

My confusion was due to the plural being used within the JSON root.

Thanks for your help Paul